# How to make custom reusable angular elements like we do in React using props

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I want to make something like this:

```
 <my-custom-component attr="sdfsdf">
    <div class="bud">
       HHello
    </div>
 </my-custom-component>
```

The functionality I want is that whatever content I put in inside the opening and closing tag of my custom element, it goes exactly where I want inside my custom component HTML code. like the following:

custom-component.html

```
 <div>
  hello
  <div> // content goes here if any </div>
 </div>
```

another-component.html

```
 <custom-component> bla bla </custom-component>
```

RESULT:

```
 <div>
  hello
  <div> bla bla  // content goes here if any  </div>
 </div>
```

I am using Angular 7

Comment: you could create  angular component and   reference it where you need it using component selector , or you if you are looking  template code reuse within component  define <ng-template  #reusable  > html code </ng-template>

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#content-projection

Here we can use

```
 <ng-content>
```

tag to tell angular where to put the content in the component when nested.